# Merging nearest neighbor polygons using R

Tags: r, join, polygon

The [figure](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vM0IzeHRoU0dYVTg/edit?pli=1) shows a plot of three polygons: 1. blue (n=1), 2. green (n=1), and 3. red (n=1).

I want to know if there is any automated way to merge the nearest neighbor same colored polygons?? A subset of the polygon can be accessed [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30veXg5clEtTURIX2s/edit).

Comment: When you say 'merge the nearest neighbours' do you mean you want to dissolve polygons that share a common boundary? What about polygons that share a common point? Your data has a lot of squares that touch at a corner (because I reckon its come from raster data)?

Comment: Any small polygon sharing a boundary or point(s) should go into a single polygon. The problem with dissolving from raster is that it makes only one large polygon. But I actually need 15-20 polygon features. It's also okay to merge polygons even though they don't share a boundary, but are very closely spaced (e.g. within 100-500 m distance). I don't care about those small polygons which are kind of isolated.

Comment: How do you imagine connecting polygons that aren't touching without changing the geometry? This is getting too complex.

Comment: Well, in that case I'd only make polygons out of those which are touching. I thought there's a way like clustering; e.g. with point data, one can use k-means to cluster points geographically.

Comment: I think we are struggling with definitions of "polygon" and "join" here. You can "cluster" separate closed polygon loops into features by some criterion, yes. Each feature may then have more than one non-contiguous loop in it.

Comment: I understand. did gMerge worked, btw?

Comment: gBuffer with a zero-size buffer width does a job of merging polygons with adjacent sides.

Comment: can you update your answer@Spacedman ? I assume you're talking about 'rgeos' package.

Comment: Can you update your question? Either its about plotting Polygon objects resulting in that error message _or_ its about merging adjacent polygons. Can't be both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42445/discussion-between-tonoy-and-spacedman)

Answer (score 1):

What you've created in `out` is a list of lists of `Polygon` class objects, so that `out[[1]][[2]]` is a `Polygon` class object.

There's no plot method for these, so you have to turn them back into `SpatialPolygons` to do that.

```
 plot(SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(out[[1]][[200]]),1001))))
```

where 1001 is an arbitrary ID and the resutling `SpatialPolygons` object doesn't have a coordinate reference system.

Its complicated because `SpatialPolygons` is actually "SpatialPolygonalFeatures" where each feature is a list of `Polygon` objects wrapped in a `Polygons` class to give it an ID.

Comment: thanks@Spacedman, but what about the major goal that I have i.e. how to make larger polygons from the small nearest neighbor polygons?? Any idea?? I've made some changes to the same question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79114/joining-nearest-neighbor-small-polygons-using-r. let me know if you have any suggestions to build on that.

Comment: Possibly gMerge from package:rgeos, but I've not got the time to set up some sample data to show you exactly how its done. Can you supply yours or a subset?